# Configure a button that links to site depending on chosen radio button

Tags: python, tkinter

So currently I have created a button that is capable of linking to a specified site (hard-coded) within this list as intended.

```
urls = ['https://steamcharts.com/top',
        'https://spotifycharts.com/regional/global/weekly/latest',
        'https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/top-anime/week'
        ]
```

Through this code:

```
def callback(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

source_bttn = Button(win, text="Show Source", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
source_bttn.pack()
source_bttn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: callback(urls[1]))
```

However, I instead want the site this buttons takes the user- to be dependent on radio button selection. Below is a simplified version of my main code

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *


# SETUP WINDOW ELEMENTS
win = Tk()
win.title("Setting Up GUI")
win.geometry("500x500")

# List elements
Titles = ["Steam Top Games\n[Title and  Current Player Count]",
          "Top Weekly Spotify Songs\n[Title and Artist]",
          "Trending Anime's Weekly\n[Title and Release Date]",
          "Steam Top Games\n[3 October 2020]"
          ]
urls = ['https://steamcharts.com/top',
        'https://spotifycharts.com/regional/global/weekly/latest',
        'https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/top-anime/week'
        ]
Options = [(Titles[0]),
           (Titles[1]),
           (Titles[2]),
           ]
# Add RadioButtons + Labels to "Current #2" frame
# Create an empty dictionary to fill with Radiobutton widgets
option_select = dict()

# create a variable class to be manipulated by Radio buttons
ttl_var = StringVar(value=" ")

# Fill radiobutton dictionary with keys from game list with Radiobutton
# values assigned to corresponding title name
for title in Options:
    option_select[title] = Radiobutton(win, variable=ttl_var, text=title, value=title,
                                    justify=LEFT)
    # Display
    option_select[title].pack(fill='both')

# Creating button link
def callback(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)


source_bttn = Button(win, text="Show Source", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
source_bttn.pack()
source_bttn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: callback(urls[1])) 

win.mainloop()
```

I'm wondering if there's a way for this `callback` function to be incorporated-somehow into `for title in Options:...` radio button line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `IntVar` instead of a `StringVar`, and then use the value to index `urls` in `callback`:

```
...

ttl_var = IntVar(value=0)

for num, title in enumerate(Titles[:-1]):
    option_select[title] = Radiobutton(win, variable=ttl_var, text=title,
                                       value=num, justify=LEFT)
    option_select[title].pack(fill='both')

def callback(event=None):
    webbrowser.open_new(urls[ttl_var.get()])

source_bttn = Button(win, text="Show Source", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
source_bttn.pack()
source_bttn.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

...
```